# Test apache pulsar functions in an embedded standalone environment

Tags: java, groovy, spock, apache-pulsar

For testing I have managed to run an embedded standalone pulsar server and client. I also can send and receive messages. However I actually want to (integration-)test functions (implementing `org.apache.pulsar.functions.api.Function`). How can I register functions in the embedded setup?

```
package kic.data.stream.pulsar

import groovy.util.logging.Log
import org.apache.pulsar.PulsarStandalone
import org.apache.pulsar.PulsarStandaloneBuilder
import org.apache.pulsar.broker.PulsarService
import org.apache.pulsar.broker.ServiceConfiguration
import org.apache.pulsar.client.api.Consumer
import org.apache.pulsar.client.api.ConsumerEventListener
import org.apache.pulsar.client.api.Message
import org.apache.pulsar.client.api.Producer
import org.apache.pulsar.client.api.PulsarClient
import org.apache.pulsar.client.api.Schema
import org.apache.pulsar.client.api.SubscriptionType
import spock.lang.Specification

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

@Log
class PulsarEmbeddedTest extends Specification {

    static final String TOPIC = "hello";
    static final int NUM_OF_MESSAGES = 100;
    static PulsarStandalone standalone
    static PulsarService pulsarService

    def setupSpec() {
        def configFile = new File(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("broker.conf").toURI()).getAbsolutePath()
        def conf = new ServiceConfiguration(clusterName: "test-cluster", zookeeperServers: "localhost:2184")
        log.info("${PulsarStandalone.properties}")
        standalone = PulsarStandaloneBuilder.instance()
                                            .withConfig(conf)
                                            .withNoStreamStorage(true)
                                            .build()
        standalone.configFile = configFile
        standalone.start()
        pulsarService = new PulsarService(conf)
    }

    def test() {
        PulsarClient client = PulsarClient.builder()
                .serviceUrl(pulsarService.brokerServiceUrl)
                .build()

        Producer<String> producer = client.newProducer(Schema.STRING)
                .topic(TOPIC)
                .enableBatching(false)
                .create()

        Consumer<String> consumer = client.newConsumer(Schema.STRING)
                .topic(TOPIC)
                //.subscriptionInitialPosition()
                .subscriptionName("test-subs-1")
                .ackTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .subscriptionType(SubscriptionType.Exclusive)
                .messageListener(Mesa)
                .subscribe()



        for (int i = 1; i <= NUM_OF_MESSAGES; ++i) {
            producer.send("Hello_" + i)
        }


        Message<String> message
        for (int i = 1; i <= NUM_OF_MESSAGES; ++i) {
            // This calls blocks until a message is available.
            message = consumer.receive(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            //log.info("Message received : ${message.getValue()}")
            println("Message received : ${message.messageId}:${message.value}")

            consumer.acknowledge(message)
        }

        producer.close()
        consumer.close()
        client.close()

        expect:
        1==1

    }

    def cleanupSpec() {
        standalone.close()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to create Pulsar Functions via the Pulsar Admin API just as you would for a normal Pulsar cluster e.g.

```
PulsarAdmin pulsarAdmin = PulsarAdmin.builder().serviceHttpUrl("http://localhost:8080").build();

FunctionConfig functionConfig = new FunctionConfig();
functionConfig.setName("exclamation");
functionConfig.setInputs(Collections.singleton("input"));
functionConfig.setClassName(ExclamationFunction.class.getName());
functionConfig.setRuntime(FunctionConfig.Runtime.JAVA);
functionConfig.setOutput("output");
functionConfig.setJar("/tmp/my-jar.jar")

pulsarAdmin.functions().createFunction(functionConfig, functionConfig.getJar());
```

There are also quite a few integration tests in the Apache Pulsar project for testing Pulsar functions.  There are docker based true integration tests and there are single process "integration" tests.  Here is an example of a single process "integration" tests that you can reference:

https://github.com/apache/pulsar/blob/master/pulsar-broker/src/test/java/org/apache/pulsar/io/PulsarFunctionE2ETest.java